# Booting is taking too long

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my SSD, and noticed the boot time being way above expected. After a bit of googling I tried debugging with dmesg, and noticed one of the biggest delays happening at this line:

```
[   93.490042] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-1800:00: attached PHY driver [Generic FE-GE  Realtek PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-1800:00, irq=IGNORE)
```

But by googling, I could neither figure out what it is, nor find anyone with similar problems, at least not in regard to boot times. I could find [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204343), where they talk about a problem possibly related to this driver, but that was impacting network connection, nothing related to boot.

The other option I considered were the lines right before this one:

```
[    4.509019] nvidia-gpu 0000:1c:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000  
[    4.509025] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110  
[    4.509027] ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

When googling for these, I found [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=206653) in which they have a problem with the same errors/GPU, and say that it takes a long while to come back from a suspended state, but with no mention to boot times. I have tried suspending and had no problems booting from a suspended state.

Is there anything else I can try?

Here is the whole paste from dmesg: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cY5k2kkh)

Output from systemd-analyze blame: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ZYzL5EWA)

Output from systemd-analyze critical-chain: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pQMpsQD6)

Comment: I tried switching graphics card drivers, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Looks like your delay occurs during `run-user-125.mount` (@1min 30.863s), which may include various subsidiary processes. Figure out what you are mounting, and why you are mounting it that way. Perhaps there is a better way...or a better time during the boot process.

Comment: I'm sorry but what would mounting be? What should I look for?

Comment: Whew. You may have a bit of a learning curve ahead, if this is a task that you really want to tackle.

Comment: Well, that sucks I guess. I was hoping there would be something I could fix with some reasonable effort, but by your comment it would seem to require some more advanced skills. Would you have any good sources I could read into?

Comment: You might check your /etc/passwd file to see what "login name" has userid 125 (/etc/passwd is a colon delimited file... the 3rd column is the "userid"... the first column is the "user name or comment field" ... To see full format enter: man 5 passwd )  The "login name"  or "user name or comment field"  may give you a "clue" to what sub-system is doing the mount.